# Matplotlib multiple xticklabel for bar graph for two columns

Tags: python

How would it look for two columns? For 'data1a', 'data2a' and 'data1b', 'data2b'?

When I try to remove the others I get the error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
d1label = ['data1a', 'data2a']
data1 = [204.24, 224.24]
d2label = ['data1b', 'data2b']
data2 = [206.24, 226.24]
d3label = ['data1c', 'data2c']
data3 = [208.24, 228.24]

width = 0.3

data = np.concatenate([data1, data2, data3])
labels = np.concatenate([d1label, d2label, d3label])
colors = np.repeat(["r", "g", "b"], [len(data1), len(data2), len(data3)])
idx = np.arange(len(data1))
x = np.concatenate([idx, idx+width, idx+width*2])
plt.bar(x, data, width=0.3, color=colors)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(x + width*0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels);
```

[image]

Reference: [matplotlib multiple xticklabel for bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148667/matplotlib-multiple-xticklabel-for-bar-graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape` happens because `x` and `data` should be the same shape. For example, if I take

```
x = np.concatenate([idx, idx+width, idx+width*2])
data = np.concatenate([data1, data2])
```

it will show the error

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Just take into account same shape for `x`, `labels`, `color` and `data`.

```
data = np.concatenate([data1, data2])
labels = np.concatenate([d1label, d2label])
colors = np.repeat(["r", "g"], [len(data1), len(data2)])
idx = np.arange(len(data1))
x = np.concatenate([idx, idx+width])
plt.bar(x, data, width=0.3, color=colors)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(x + width*0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels);
```

will output

[image]